# Data Fetching time when no primary key in select and where cluase?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

1) if i have  table t1 have primary key p1.

2) if i have  table t2 and have no primary key.

**Assumption**

t1 and t2 have the same number of rows same data except the constraint(Primary key).

1.1) if we don't select the primary key column and don't apply filter on the basis of primary key.

2.1) if we select the rows from a table t2.

Both Query will take the same time for execution.?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key constraint don't affect performance unless some rare specific cases.

Indexes (made by primary key among others) frequently affect performance.

If query execution plan for select statement don't use index, it works same time whether index exists or not.